# Completely Disable Wordpress RSS Feeds

Tags: functions, css, rss

There are loads of articles out there on how to completely disable Wordpress RSS feeds, my configuration (`functions.php`) is:

```
function disable_feed() {
  wp_die( 'You Died' , 200 );
}
add_action('do_feed', 'disable_feed', 1);
add_action('do_feed_rdf', 'disable_feed', 1);
add_action('do_feed_rss', 'disable_feed', 1);
add_action('do_feed_rss2', 'disable_feed', 1);
add_action('do_feed_atom', 'disable_feed', 1);
add_action('do_feed_rss2_comments', 'disable_feed', 1);
add_action('do_feed_atom_comments', 'disable_feed', 1);
```

But instead of getting a nice-looking HTML page with the bordered content normally associated with the `wp_die()` function, when browsing to https://website/feed/ I'm getting this knarley page back:

[image]

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

David.

Comment: See https://wordpress.org/support/topic/completely-disable-wordpress-rss-feeds/

Answer (score 0):

Add following code to: functions.php

```
 function itsme_disable_feed() {
     wp_die( __( 'No feed available, please visit the <a href="'. esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ) .'">homepage</a>!' ) );
    }

add_action('do_feed', 'itsme_disable_feed', 1);
add_action('do_feed_rdf', 'itsme_disable_feed', 1);
add_action('do_feed_rss', 'itsme_disable_feed', 1);
add_action('do_feed_rss2', 'itsme_disable_feed', 1);
add_action('do_feed_atom', 'itsme_disable_feed', 1);
add_action('do_feed_rss2_comments', 'itsme_disable_feed', 1);
add_action('do_feed_atom_comments', 'itsme_disable_feed', 1);

remove_action( 'wp_head', 'feed_links_extra', 3 );
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'feed_links', 2 );
```

Comment: That's actually the first one I tried. Same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I just couldn't get this to work. I was expecting the `wp_die()` function to provide its message on a pretty HTML page, like this example: https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-disable-rss-feeds-in-wordpress/

...but all I get is this nasty XML tree.

I've changed my solution now to instead HTTP302 redirect the visitor to ./feed/ to the homepage. This is actually a better solution, I believe, because it means Wordpress is not run.

Comment: A 302 redirect to the home page is not a good choice, it would be better to send 404.